# App crashes when implementing a simple textview in Kotlin/xml

Tags: kotlin

when textView_hourly is set to any value the app will build successfully but will crash when opened. This is not in my MainActivity. I am implementing this activity as a fragment to be placed within the main activity through a ViewPager.

```
class HourlyActivity : Fragment(){

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? 
    {
        textView_hourly.text = "yo"
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hourly,container,false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to set the text in a fragment, how about moving the textview code to onActivityCreated instead?

Comment: you should move it to onViewCreated function, it's not a good practice to do this in onActivityCreated function @MozartLeak